# Color KML Objects grouped

Tags: kml

I have a question regarding groups in KML.

I have a dataset, consisting of 50 objects. These objects have attributes,f.e severity. Is there any possibility to classify my KML-document based on these severity classes? (1/1.5/2) Or based on any of the other attributes?I already created folders manually, but the bigger the dataset gets the more work it is...  I would also like to color the objects, based on the classification. Attached I will add my document. Maybe anyone has an idea how to approach this?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="Flood_2017_KML" id="Flood_2017_KML">
    <SimpleField name="ID" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="GlideNumbe" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Country" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="OtherCount" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="long" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="lat" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Area" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Began" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Ended" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Validation" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Dead" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Displaced" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="MainCause" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Severity" type="float"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>Flood_2017_KML</name>
<Folder id="Severity1_flood_2017">
<Style id="transGreyPoly">
  <LineStyle>
    <width>1</width>
    <color>3c8C8C8C</color>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>3c8C8C8C</color>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
   <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4441</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Peru</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">-77.572950000000006</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">-5.250831000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">288499.131403999985196</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/02/01</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/02/07</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">12000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">1.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-78.859612,-8.472832 -80.740118,-5.695045 -79.255508,-4.505716 -77.57295,-2.721449 -74.405783,-2.02883 -74.702704,-5.995598 -78.859612,-8.472832</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4457</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Angola</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">13.656325000000001</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">-8.717518999999999</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">24002.582783800000470</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/03/21</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/04/08</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">11</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">344</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">1.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>14.126451,-9.709634 13.384147,-9.758848 12.988251,-8.965265 13.186199,-8.519087 13.087225,-7.77524 13.33466,-7.676191 14.324399,-8.321313 14.126451,-9.709634</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>y
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4460</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Malawi</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">33.871761999999997</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">-10.364181000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">24405.783080000001064</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/04/04</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/04/18</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">4</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">1.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>34.56458,-11.306672 33.228432,-11.206827 33.178945,-9.42169 34.119197,-9.521335 34.56458,-11.306672</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  <Folder id="Severity1.5_flood_2017">
  <Style id="transGreenPoly">
  <LineStyle>
    <width>1</width>
    <color>507832F0</color>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>507832F0</color>
  </PolyStyle>
  </Style>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4433</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Germany</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">9.583276000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">54.705274000000003</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">18991.845394600000873</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/01/02</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/01/05</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Winter Storm Axel</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">1.500000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>13.532608,54.306792 13.33466,53.662268 10.414927,53.415802 9.425187,54.457616 9.227239,55.251098 9.524161,55.994746 9.920057,55.944961 9.623135,54.953381 10.019031,54.407731 10.761336,54.109839 11.058258,53.911344 12.493381,54.009796 13.532608,54.306792</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  <Folder id="Severity2_flood_2017">
  <Style id="transPinkPoly">
  <LineStyle>
    <width>1</width>
    <color>5014B45A</color>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>5014B45A</color>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
   <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4445</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Chile</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">-70.248874999999998</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">-30.939481000000001</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">183781.025771999993594</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/02/24</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/03/03</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">3</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">1200</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">2.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-70.644771,-35.947863 -72.030407,-36.04634 -71.733485,-32.277917 -71.634511,-29.699471 -70.842719,-26.129643 -69.852979,-25.832622 -68.467343,-26.626701 -69.358109,-28.411367 -69.951953,-30.4937 -70.347849,-31.782749 -70.248875,-33.072047 -70.644771,-35.947863</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4450</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GlideNumbe">FL-2017-000018-PER</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Peru</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">-75.148087000000004</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">-11.004229000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">810942.342724999994971</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/02/01</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/03/22</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">78</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">70000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">2.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-70.050927,-17.99786 -73.020147,-16.70712 -76.08834,-14.226255 -78.56269,-9.960576 -80.938066,-4.504871 -77.770898,-4.010598 -75.989366,-6.094124 -73.119121,-9.566619 -69.358109,-14.626329 -70.050927,-17.99786</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4456</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GlideNumbe">MS-2017-000033-COL</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Colombia</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">-76.113083000000003</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">2.187014000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">28634.320610300001135</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/04/01</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/04/08</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">314</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">2.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-75.197574,1.640966 -76.286288,1.343995 -77.028593,1.939405 -76.880132,2.881474 -76.484236,3.030034 -75.741931,3.029661 -75.346035,2.434424 -75.197574,1.640966</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4463</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GlideNumbe">FL-2017-000038-IRN</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Iran</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">46.169280000000001</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">37.704303000000003</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">40807.872714999997697</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/04/15</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/04/21</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">42</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Torrential Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">2.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>47.530173,37.35593 46.738381,36.711703 45.204284,36.662888 44.808388,38.745718 46.639407,38.645625 47.530173,37.35593</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4458</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GlideNumbe">TC-2017-000031-AUS</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">Australia</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="OtherCount">New Zealand</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">148.681590000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">-21.974972999999999</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">258485.657990000006976</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/03/28</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/04/08</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">6</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">20000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Tropical Cyclone Debbie</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">2.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>152.244654,-25.250018 149.077487,-25.645118 146.900059,-23.858911 145.118527,-20.089444 146.108267,-18.304829 147.295955,-19.693847 148.879539,-20.686372 149.671331,-22.471883 152.046707,-24.258189 152.244654,-25.250018</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
        <SimpleData name="ID">4461</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Country">New Zealand</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">176.790203999999989</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">-38.204245999999998</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area">23530.760163599999942</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Began">2017/04/05</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/04/21</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Dead">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Displaced">2200</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Severity">2.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>178.027379,-37.758764 177.334561,-39.196423 175.800464,-38.898133 175.553029,-37.212069 175.948925,-37.4602 176.592256,-38.005975 177.384048,-38.055959 178.027379,-37.758764</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  </Folder>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

Comment: What are you using to display the KML?

Comment: The aim is to use the kml for further visualiszation outside of Google Earth. For a study I am right now comparing vector formats and their possibilities in styling options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're working in Google Earth, unfortunately you'll need to try some different software for this.  Google Earth does not have a way to do automatic grouping or classification on KML files. The only option it has for such things is in the import workflow, like when you're importing a shapefile in to Earth Pro and choose to use buckets for styling.

This is the kind of thing that you'll probably want to do in some GIS software with real analytical capabilities. QGIS is a great option that's free and open source, though it does have a bit of a learning curve. In there you'll be able to maintain your dataset, do grouping by attributes, and export to KML.

Comment: Thank you Christian! I havent thought about this option. I already exported the KML from QGIS, but without the classification. So I am definitely going to try this out. Thank you for the input!

Comment: As it seems it does not work due to a bug that has not been fixed yet. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13688